# CMS для портала с нагрузкой

Tags: wordpress, cms, joomla, drupal

Друзья, добрый день!

Заинтересовала тема поиска CMS для веб-портала. Под порталом имеется в виду - текстовый раздел (новости, статьи, блог) и пользовательский (объявления, форум и так далее).

Из известных CMS напрашивается что угодно с кастомизируемыми полями и выводом, плюс немного программирования. Думаю, это может быть и Drupal, и Wordpress, и много чего ещё.

Другой вопрос - нагрузка в плане посещаемости и количества материалов. Даже если вопрос с посещаемостью может быть решён железом, то вопрос с количеством материалов бывает весьма актуальным. Не раз слышал фразу "база поломалась" и так далее. В общем, сайт дальше не работает. Как-то чинят, конечно, но не хотелось бы с этим столкнуться, наперед зная, что такое может быть.

Из "продвинутых" функций планируется, пожалуй, полнотекстовый поиск, а так ничего другого пока на ум не приходит... регистрация, логин, добавление каментов, каких-то других  материалов, хотелось бы иметь кеширование, конечно.

Спасибо!

Comment: Про какие объемы и нагрузки идет речь?

Comment: Тут вопрос больше не в движке, а в руках/специалистах.

Comment: https://kagg.eu/10000-clients-second-wordpress/